# iMac connected to Wi-Fi but not to the Internet

Tags: macos, wifi, imac

I have a 2009 iMac (24 inch) running El Capitan (10.11.6). For a few days I have not been able to connect to the internet. The Wi-Fi network is connected to the internet because I can access it with my other devices.

I have turned Wi-Fi on and off in System Preferences but that did not help. I can also see a good IP address in System Preferences.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the output of `ifconfig en1`?  Also, please provide the output of `route -n get default`  Please post the results by **editing the original question**

Comment: Problem solved by running Diagnostics. There was a DNS settings issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to diagnose your internet connection:

```
System Preferences -> Network -> Assist me… -> Diagnostics…
```

[image: Network settings]

Comment: That worked! There was a problem with the DNS settings. Your help was much appreciated?

Comment: @Marcus If this answer solved your problem, it would be great if you marked it as the answer by clicking the check mark below the downvote button.